# .htaccess redirect anywhere except a specific directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to edit .htaccess so that it would display a redirect to my /main/ directory when I visit a page that is not in the /main/ directory. How would I go on about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I think:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^main/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ redirect_file.php [L]
```

would do it